# Read numbers between delimiters from files

Tags: c, regex

I have to read numbers from a file that are separated by paranthesis or different symbols like the following:

(58) [787" {91} (-66]

There is always a space between the numbers and their separators.
What is have done so far is this:

```
fgets(line, MAXLINE, source.txt)
line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
value = strtok(line, " ");
while(value != NULL)
{
    nr = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(value) - 1; i++)
        nr = nr * 10 + value[i] - '0';
    value = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Unfortunately, my approach does not work for negative numbers or decimals.
I suspect there is a better way of doing this with regex.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not c#...changing tag to c

Comment: you should start with hard coded strings to test your analyzer. Make some simple strings first and then more complex ones. No need to use the file input at the start. Also, you should write two functions, one to clean the input and one to do the conversion.

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` is not needed and wrong in select cases.  Suggest dropping it and use `strtok(..., " \n");`

Comment: Instead of `for(i = 1; i < strlen(value) - 1; i++)
        nr = nr * 10 + value[i] - '0';`, get code working with `nr = atof(value);`  Then replace the `atof()` with your own code if desired.

Comment: Even better: [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) because it also returns a pointer to the next character to be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you *have to read numbers from a file*, you can leave the work of checking whether there's a number to the file reading and conversion function. This example finds all numbers in the standard input stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float number;
    do  switch (scanf("%f", &number))   // try to read a number
        {
        case 0: getchar();  break;      // failure - skip character
        case 1: printf("%f\n", number); // success - print number
        }
     while (!feof(stdin));
}
```